# get double corruption error when trying to reallocate dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

There is a piece of code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>

    using std::cout, std::endl;

    struct Chunk{
      Chunk(){}
      int* get(){ return reinterpret_cast<int*>(&_data[0]);}
      unsigned char _data[sizeof(int)];
    };

    class MemoryPool{
    public:
      MemoryPool(size_t capacity):_capacity(capacity)
      {
        _size=0;
        _data=new Chunk[_capacity];
        _vacant=new bool[_capacity];
        for(int i=0; i<_capacity; ++i) _vacant[i]=true;
      }
      ~MemoryPool()
      {
        delete [] _data;
        delete [] _vacant;
      }
      size_t size() const {return _size;}
      size_t capacity() const {return _capacity;}
      int* allocate()
      {
        int index=find_vacant();
        if(-1 == index)
        {
          reallocate();
          index=find_vacant();
        }
        _vacant[index]=false;
        ++_size;
        return get(index);
      }
      void reallocate()
      {
        const int new_capacity=2*_capacity+1;
        Chunk* new_data  =new Chunk[new_capacity];
        bool*  new_vacant=new bool[new_capacity];
        std::memcpy(new_data, _data, _size*sizeof(Chunk));
        std::memcpy(new_vacant, _vacant, _size*sizeof(bool));
        for(int i=_size; i<new_capacity; ++i) new_vacant[i]=true;
        std::swap(_data,new_data);
        std::swap(_vacant,new_vacant);
        delete [] new_data;
        delete [] new_vacant;
        _capacity=new_capacity;
      }  
      int* get(int index)
      {
        return reinterpret_cast<int*>(&_data[index]);
      }
      int find_vacant()
      {
        int index=-1;
        for(int i=0; i<(int)_capacity; ++i)
        {
          if(_vacant[i])
          {
            index=i;
            break;
          }
        }
        return index;
      }  
    private:
      size_t _size;
      size_t _capacity;
      Chunk* _data;
      bool* _vacant;
    };

    int main()
    {
      MemoryPool pool(10);
      cout<<"pool.size()="<<pool.size()<<endl;
      for(int i=0; i<11; ++i)
      {
        int* ptr=pool.allocate();
        *ptr=i+1;
      }
      cout<<"PRINT:"<<endl;
      for(int i=0; i<pool.size(); ++i) cout<<*(pool.get(i))<<" ";
      cout<<endl;
      return 0;
    }
```

The code fails at the end of runtime with a double corruption error:

```
    double free or corruption (out)
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

The error occurs in the destructor *~MemoryPool()* when calling *delete []* operators for the pointers pointing to the arrays.
I tried to use

```
   valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out
```

It points to the *reallocate()* function, but I can't understand the output of *valgrind*.

Of course, I know that it is not recommended to work with dynamic memory allocation directly and strongly recommended to use STL containers.

As for my question, it must be some silly error, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. It seemes to me that I allocate and delete the dynamic arrays properly.

Comment: Why 11 pool allocations for `pool(10)`?

Comment: The MemoryPool object should call reallocate() and allocate the extra necessary space to store the demanded number of elements.

Comment: You leave the "extra space" in `_vacant` uninitialized when you reallocate.

Comment: After you fix the problem you're having, you still have "Rule of Five" violations.

Comment: If you use `false` to indicate vacancy (that is, have an "occupied" array instead), you can let the machine initialize the occupancy table with `new bool[_capacity]()` and avoid some bugs.

Comment: `std::memcpy(new_vacant, _vacant, _size * sizeof(Chunk));` clearly that's wrong. `new_vacant` points to a sequence of `bool`, not `Chunk`

Comment: @molbdnilo, Thank You, Sir. Corrected this issue. But the error is the same.

Comment: The "safer `memcpy` formula" is `memcpy(target, source, size * sizeof(*target))` (or `sizeof(*source)`).

Comment: Or screw memcpy. This is C++. Objects can be complex (even if yours aren't). Use `std::copy(_data, _data+size, new_data);` etc. and let the optimizer work out the intrinsic instructions for bulk-copy if it is an option.

Comment: Why don't you use std::vector instead? And you really should think about how to implement your copy and move destructors (or delete them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not set the `new_vacant` array up correctly. In the constructor you have a small loop that ensures that all spaces in your `MemoryPool` are vacant:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < _capacity; ++i)
    _vacant[i] = true;
```

This loop is missing in `reallocate()`.

Why does this matter? Because right after calling `reallocate()` you call `index = find_vacant()`, and then you straight up use that index `_vacant[index] = false` and `*ptr = i + 1`.

However, since your entire array is marked as "used up" you are getting index -1. Which again means that you are writing into `_vacant[-1]` and `_data[-1]` - I hope you see the problem.

Also, I think (very not sure, may also be implementation defined) that `new` uses some of the space "in front" of the chunk you get to place allocation information into (stuff like number of elements etc.) - so that may be what you are overwriting here.

Comment: Yes, the error was in the line: _vacant[i]=true; in reallocate(). After being pointed to this place, I corrected the source code here, but didn't locally on my machine. But this replacement _vacant[i] -> new_vacant[i] removed the error. I finally understood what the problem was. Thank You very much for Your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::memcpy(new_data, _data, _size*sizeof(Chunk));
std::memcpy(new_vacant, _vacant, _size*sizeof(Chunk)); <-- Copy&paste error
```

Comment: I beg Your pardon, Sir, there was a silly error. But after fixing it the runtime error is the same.

Comment: "the runtime error is the same" No it is not.

Comment: Sorry, but on Ubuntu 20.04 g++ version 9.3.0 the program is frozen in ~MemoryPool().

Comment: Maybe some version of the program does, but not the one I tested. You keep changing your code each time an error is pointed out to you. It is hard to follow a moving target.

Comment: You are right. After having been pointed to this place, I corrected the code here: _vacant[i] -> new_vacant[i], but didn't on my local machine. But that solved the problem. Sorry and thank You.